# Avoiding extra heap allocations with composition (over inheritance)?

Tags: c++, inheritance

tl;dr - Composition seems like the right design choice for my situation, but I'd like to avoid the overhead of heap allocations for each object I'm composing together. Any good techniques?

I have a setup that looks like:

```
class Foo {
  public:
    Foo(unique_ptr<FooEvaluator> evaluator) 
    : evaluator_(std::move(evaluator)),
      common_state_() {}

    void FooMethod() {
      // Perform some common processing.
      evaluator.DoSomething();
    }
  private:
    unique_ptr<FooEvaluator> evaluator_;
    Bar common_state_;
}

class FooEvaluator {
  public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
}

class FooEvaluatorImpl : public FooEvaluator {
  public:
    FooEvaluatorImpl(type1 arg) {…}

    void DoSomething() override {…}
}

class FooEvaluatorImplVariant : public FooEvaluator {
  public:
    FooEvaluatorImplVariant(type2 arg) {…}

    void DoSomething() override {…}
}
```

Roughly: I have a Foo which does some common processing, and then uses a FooEvaluator. I have a handful of FooEvaluator implementations that each have some different logic. The common Foo processing is sufficiently non-trivial that it makes sense to try to avoid duplicating it.

My concern is that now I have to allocate two objects, instead of only one if I had a monolithic Foo that contained both the shared logic and the evaluation logic.

One vaguely reasonable middle ground I can think of is to have FooEvaluator inherit from Foo, and add `DoSomething()` as a private virtual method on Foo. It's a bit of an abuse of inheritance imo (you can't say that a FooEvaluator "is a" Foo), but it would get my shared code and avoid the double memory allocation.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are all of the Foo Evaluator's roughly the same size? If so, I'd make them into a std::variant or boost:variant and have a visitor function that implements what would normally be the virtual function interface.

Comment: Can you replace virtual inheritance with the crtp, i.e. do the composition at compile time? That kills off the unique_ptr, heap allocations and vtables in exchange for losing the type erasure (or moving it up a level).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by 'composition'? Can you give an example? I don't understand how composition could result in multiple allocations. (Probably my own ignorance though!)

Comment: @RyanP interesting - hadn't thought of that. Looks like a great solution.

Comment: @AaronMcDaid I just mean that I have to allocate a Foo and also a FooEvaluatorImpl (which gets passed to the Foo constructor). If FooEvaluatorImpl were a subclass that extended Foo, then I would just allocate a single FooEvaluatorImpl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may do something like that with template:

```
template <typename Evaluator>
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename ... Ts>
    Foo(Ts&&... args) 
    : evaluator_(std::forward<Ts>(args)...),
      common_state_()
    {}

    void FooMethod() {
      // Perform some common processing.
      evaluator.DoSomething();
    }
private:
    Evaluator evaluator_;
    Bar common_state_;
};
```

Comment: This seems like by-far the best solution. I'll leave it unaccepted for a day to see if anybody suggests something different.

Answer (score -1):

Well, since I have no idea about Foo's complexity/details, I would suggest making it an **inline function**, and then you could call it from the several FooEvaluator instances, in order to accomplish the common processing, before doing the specifics.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of detail - Foo has some state, which unfortunately means that this won't work (I think?)

Comment: Yes you're right. Can't you move the 'common processing' to the base FooEvaluator class; remove Foo, keep only a Bar class containing the state, and make the FooEvaluators instances have a Bar* in order to reference the existing state info needed to perform the processing?